# non lineaire SVM in OpenCv 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm using a program for road recognition in C++ (visual studio 2013), and I would classify the road sign with a non lineaire SVM, but I don't know how to select its parameters in OpenCv 3.0.
this is what I tried, it classify the road reconied in the best class (for example 60 Km/h, 80Km/h...), but when I give to it an other road sing not reconied by it, it classified it in one of thre classes (60/80/100), con you please tell me what is the parameters of non lineaire SVM in OpenCv 3.0.0 .

```
svm = SVM::create();
    svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(SVM::KernelTypes::LINEAR);

    svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 500, 1e-6));


    toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Training begin .....";
    Ptr<ml::TrainData> tData = ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, traningLabels);
    svm->train(tData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks, just like most classifiers will put objects into the classes they know. If you told it the world exists of 3 classes, it will put the world in those 3 classes. No big surprise there.

There are many ways to tackle this. By far the most common is to just add a category "other" in training, and feed it thousands of other images.

In this particular case, I'd use 3 extra "other" classes: similarly-shaped road signs (i.e. round with red edge for Euro speed limits), all other roadside signs, and "not a roadsign".

Comment: thak you for your answer, but your suggestion, I tried it, and I used an images negative (for represente any other image-not a road sing), but, the problem that is my classifier clyssify it in the nearest class.

Comment: my teatcher tell me that this problem is non lineair, but I don't know what is the type that I can specify in OpenCv 3.0